# Accessing a hash with symbol or integer

Tags: ruby, string, hash, symbols

I have this hash:

```
@current_user.birthday = { "birthday" => "12/01/1978", "id" => "524626626" }
```

I would like to grab the date `"12/01/1978"`.

I tried `@current_user.birthday[:birthday]`, only to get `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

What's the proper way?

EDIT

I think the output is a string instead

`puts @current_user.birthday` gives me `{"birthday"=>"09/21/1985", "id"=>"425495284312580"}`

`puts @current_user.birthday[0..3]` gives me `{"bi`

I can possibly get it by `@current_user.birthday[14..23]` which puts out `12/01/1978`. But is there a better way, in the event there are multiple birthdays

Comment: It seems `@current_user.birthday` is an `Array`

Comment: don't arrays have [ ]?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: I'd guess that `@current_user.birthday` isn't what you think it is

Comment: As Frederick and others suggest, `@current_user.birthday` definitely isn't a Hash. Can you edit your question to include the output of `puts @current_user.birthday.inspect`?

Comment: You guys are right. I've edited the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of using `puts`, try using `p`.  `p` will inspect the object before printing it.  If you see quotes, it is indeed probably a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is with the Hash printed as a String. I used `eval` to convert it into a Hash

`@current_user.birthday = {"birthday"=>"09/21/1985", "id"=>"425495284312580"}`

`birthday = @current_user.birthday
hash = eval(birthday)`

`puts hash["birthday"]` => `12/01/1978`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
@current_user.birthday["birthday"]
```

Your `birthday` isn't a symbol but string.

Comment: If I do that, it just gives me `birthday`. Doesn't give me the dates